# Does C# Compiler Treat Array Element Differently From The Same Type Variable?! (System.ArrayTypeMismatchException)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I was working on something today, but I noticed something in the code, so let me explain the situation.

I get data as IEnumerable from different concreate classes of interface, look at this sample code

```
public interface ISampleClass {
    IEnumerable<ISampleClass> GetSampleData();
}

public class SampleClassAsPerson : ISampleClass
{
    public IEnumerable<ISampleClass> GetSampleData()
    {
        // Return data from DB
        // Return list for this example
        return new List<SampleClassAsPerson>() {new SampleClassAsPerson(), new SampleClassAsPerson()};
    }
}
```

I put the data that comes from **GetSampleData()** method in Array of my Interface(will see this in the code bellow), I noticed that my Array not holding the same data as the variable from the same type, lets look at the code

```
public class TestArrayAndSingle
{
    public const byte ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    public const byte FIRST_PLACE_IN_ARRAY = 0;

    public static void DoTheTest()
    {
        // First as single element
        IEnumerable<ISampleClass> singleIEnumerable = new List<ISampleClass>();
        singleIEnumerable = new SampleClassAsPerson().GetSampleData(); // Works Fine for variable of type new List<ISampleClass>()


        // Second as array of elements 
        IEnumerable<ISampleClass>[] arrayOfIEnumerable = new IEnumerable<ISampleClass>[ARRAY_SIZE];
        arrayOfIEnumerable[FIRST_PLACE_IN_ARRAY] = new SampleClassAsPerson().GetSampleData(); // Works fine also


        IEnumerable<ISampleClass>[] arrayOfList = new List<ISampleClass>[ARRAY_SIZE];
        arrayOfList[FIRST_PLACE_IN_ARRAY] = new SampleClassAsPerson().GetSampleData(); // Return ArrayTypeMismatchException, This should be the same as singleIEnumerable I guess(new List<ISampleClass>())
    }
}
```

So for the first one IEnumerable singleIEnumerable = new List(); works fine but in IEnumerable[] arrayOfList = new List[ARRAY_SIZE]; first item gives exception (System.ArrayTypeMismatchException - Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.).

Can anyone explain why? does element in array treated differently  from same type variable?!

Comment: `// Works Fine for variable of type new List<ISampleClass>()` - except it's not. It's a variable with a declared type of `IEnumerable<ISampleClass>`.

Comment: Since you're not using `var`, you can see all of the declared types of your variables easily - they're the types given before the variable names. Part of your confusion seems to be around declared types *vs* initialization, but I'm not sure how best it's addressed.

Comment: [Array covariance: not just ugly, but slow too | Jon Skeet's coding blog](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/06/22/array-covariance-not-just-ugly-but-slow-too/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a collection of `List<T>` and are trying to store a more generic `IEnumerable<T>` in it. but not all `IEnumerable<T>`s  are lists, so the compiler doesn't allow it. What if the `IEnumerable<T>` was a stack? or a linked list? or a LINQ query?

With a array of a certain type, you can store items that are of that type or *more* specific, but not *less* specific. So you can store lists in an array of enumerables (because all lists are enumerables), but not enumerables in an array of lists (since not all enumerables are lists).

Comment: I think I got your point, thanks.